# Urban Airship Android addTag response?

Tags: java, android, urbanairship.com

I might be misunderstanding how this works, but is there no way to get a response when adding a tag?

After reading the documentation, I see to added a device to a tag. I use the following.

```
public void addTag(String tag) {
    UAirship.shared().getPushManager().editTags().addTag(tag).apply();
}
```

Looking at Urban Airships documentation for apply, http://docs.urbanairship.com/reference/libraries/android/latest/reference/com/urbanairship/push/TagEditor.html#apply()

It shows that it does not return anything. So is there no way to know for sure that a device was successfully added to a tag? I feel like I am misunderstanding how this works since it seems that this is making an API call essentially so there is a chance it could fail.

Comment: It looks like I can do `UAirship.shared().getPushManager().getTags()` to return a set of tags that have been assigned so one possibility is to run that and check that the tag has been added. That just seems a little dirty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the Urban Airship SDKs will automatically handle the retry internally if the tag operation fails to complete. Its more of a set and forget about it type operation.

For channel tags, like the example above, tags are applied during channel registration. You can listen for channel updates in the Airship Receiver's [onChannelUpdated](http://docs.urbanairship.com/platform/android.html#listening-for-push-events). For tag groups no such callback is available at the moment. If you would like better feedback, you please contact Urban Airship support to request an enhancement.